# How to load data dynamically to the angular application based on the domain name in AWS?

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have built an angular application and deployed it to AWS S3 and using AWS Lambda as the backend. I want different domains to access the angular application (ex: abc.com /abc.org) and I know that is possible with CloudFront. But I want to dynamically load data to the angular application based on the domain name.

Is there any way to do this? Any help?

Answer (score 0):

We have a single angular application and it is displaying data and applying themes differently based on the domain.

- If it is static content
  config file we configured in the form of json, based on that we are disabling/ enabling the content.
- If it is dynamic data from the backend
  We are passing domain data through HTTP requests to fetch different content.